# If detA =3 for some nxn matrix, what is det(A^T A)?

Tags: matrices, determinant, transpose

If $\det(A) =3$ for some $n\times n$ matrix, what is $\det(A^{T} A)$?
I know that $\det (A)=\det(A^T)$ but combined?

Comment: What are your thoughts? Do you know any theorems about det?

Comment: You should know that for any $n\times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$ one has $\det(BA)=\det(B)\det(A)$.  This is in particular true when $B=A^T$.

Comment: Determinants are multiplicative.

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\mat}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}$
$$
\det (\mat A^\intercal \mat A) = \det \mat{A}^\intercal \det \mat A = (\det \mat A)^2
$$

Comment: Thank you for your clear reply!